# Pandas to_json not correctly formatting json file?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a data frame I'm attempting to export to a json file. Currently my fame looks something like this

```
PRICE    FRUIT    COLOR
1        Apple    Red
2        Orange   Orange
```

When I use the following JSON call:

```
df.to_json(orient='records',lines=True)
```

I return

```
{'Price':1,'Fruit':Apple,'Color':Red}
{'Price':2,'Fruit':Orange,'Color':Orange}
```

when I want

```
[{'Price':1,'Fruit':Apple,'Color':Red}
{'Price':2,'Fruit':Orange,'Color':Orange}]
```

So that the JSON file doesn't read each item as the end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

According to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#:%7E:text=a%20serialisable%20object.-,linesbool,-%2C%20default%20False), if `lines=True`, pandas writes out line-delimited json format.